# Date Range search using NEST doesn't return data

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I want to use Date Range search in Elasticsearch using NEST API.

Simply it works when I search like this:

```
                        .DateRange(c => c
                            .Name("myquery")
                            .Boost(1.1)
                            .Field(p => p.CreatedOnUtc)
                            .GreaterThanOrEquals(DateMath.Now.Subtract("3d")) //this works fine
                            .LessThanOrEquals(DateMath.Now)
                            .Format("dd/MM/yyyy||yyyy")
                            .TimeZone("+01:00")
                            )
```

Bu when I want to use my custom **fromDate** Datetime value instead of **DateMath.Now.Subtract("3d")** it doesn't return anything!

I tried many different lines of code as below but none of them worked!

```
.GreaterThan(DateMath.Anchored(fromDate))
```

or

```
.GreaterThanOrEquals(DateMath.Anchored(fromDate).RoundTo(DateMathTimeUnit.Day))
```

or

```
.GreaterThan(new DateTime(2012, 01, 01, 11, 0, 0))
```

Returned sample json value for my datetime filed is:

```
"createdOnUtc": "2020-04-08T15:53:36.4800870Z"
```

I found related documentation/samplequery on Elasticsearch website as located [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/7.x/date-range-query-usage.html) but it doesn't helped me, here I copying Object Initializer syntax example from documentation:

```
new DateRangeQuery
{
    Name = "named_query",
    Boost = 1.1,
    Field = "description",
    GreaterThan = FixedDate,
    GreaterThanOrEqualTo = DateMath.Anchored(FixedDate).RoundTo(DateMathTimeUnit.Month),
    LessThan = "01/01/2012",
    LessThanOrEqualTo = DateMath.Now,
    TimeZone = "+01:00",
    Format = "dd/MM/yyyy||yyyy"
}
```

Is the problem related to Format/TimeZone or what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `Format = "dd/MM/yyyy||yyyy"` is specified on the request, Elasticsearch expects to receive a DateTime string in one of these formats, and will use the supplied format(s) to attempt to parse a DateTime string into a valid instance of a DateTime within Elasticsearch.

With

```
DateMath.Anchored(fromDate)
```

or

```
new DateTime(2012, 01, 01, 11, 0, 0)
```

the client will [serialize these to an ISO8601 DateTime string representations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/date-math-expressions.html), so the input for these values don't match the supplied format(s) in the request.

Looking at your first example above, it looks like you don't need to specify a value for `Format`. When there's no format specified, Elasticsearch will use the format specified in the `date` field mapping for `CreatedOnUtc`, and if there isn't one, will use [the default `"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"` format for date types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html#date), which will parse ISO8601 date strings produced by the client.